# Is there an umbrella term in Latin for stage plays and dialogues?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request

What would be the idiomatic way to refer to dialogues and stage plays together in Latin? That is literary forms where the main speech is direct

Comment: Are there corresponding terms in other languages?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I think I read something like "littérature vivante" or something in French

Comment: Dialogue isn't really a genre in Latin literature, and the few dialogues that did exist won't have been seen as particularly close to the various kinds of drama (which were all in verse).

Comment: @Cairnarvon Weren't most of Cicero's philosophical works dialogues?

Comment: @John Yes, and he's very nearly the only Roman who wrote any. To the extent that they would have been seen as any genre at all, they would likely have been considered philosophical tracts rather than dialogues as a distinct thing.